# Phalcon PUT method not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, phalcon

I have write a website by using the Phalcon Micro Application.

When deploy the web on my localhost, it work fine with the all HTTP METHOD.

However, when deploy my web into real host, that is public access. I face a problem that when calling api PUT, the server return 404 not found.
Below is my code:

```
$app->put('/api/news/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
$new = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();
$phql = "UPDATE News SET title = :title:, img = :img:, htmlContent = :htmlContent:, tag = :tag:, area = :area:, address = :address:, city=:city:, district = :district:, province = :province:, street = :street:, ward = :ward:, modifiedDate = :modifiedDate: WHERE id = :id:";
$status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array(
    'id' => $id,
    'title' => $new->title,
    'img' => $new->img,
    'htmlContent' => $new->htmlContent,
    'area' => $new->area,
    'address' => $new->address,
    'city' => $new->city,
    'district' => $new->district,
    'province' => $new->province,
    'street' => $new->street,
    'ward' => $new->ward,
    'tag' => $new->tag,
    'modifiedDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));

// Create a response
$response = new Response();
// Check if the insertion was successful
if ($status->success() == true) {
    $response->setJsonContent(
        array(
            'status' => 'OK'
        )
    );
} else {

    // Change the HTTP status
    $response->setStatusCode(409, "Conflict");

    $errors = array();
    foreach ($status->getMessages() as $message) {
        $errors[] = $message->getMessage();
    }

    $response->setJsonContent(
        array(
            'status' => 'ERROR',
            'messages' => $errors
        )
    );
}

return $response;
```

});

I guess that this is a cross domain problem then I try with this setup on .htaccess but it doesn't help.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Appreciate for any helps on this.